# ActionCable отправка сообщения

Tags: javascript, websocket

пришлось использовать библиотеку ws `ActionCable` в проекте но столкнулся скорее всего с недопониманием. Как отправить такое сообщение с такой командой и передать `body` в `ActionCable`? В документации этого не описано.

В общем должна уйти такая команда на сервер с такими данными:

```
const subscribeCommand = JSON.stringify({
  command: 'message',
  identifier: {
    channel: 'ChatRoomChannel',
    chat_room_id: id // typeof number
  },
  data: {
    action: 'send_message',
    data: {
      body: data.message.message, // typeof string
      chat_room_id: id // typeof number
    }
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Пришлось помучатся, всем кому придется с ним работать возможно поможет. Что-бы отправить сообщение на сервер достаточно к сабскрайбу добавить метод `sendMessage` и вызывать его передавая ему свои параметры `mySubscription.sendMessage(...params)`.

```js
let subscription = null;
let cable = Cable.createConsumer(`wss://YOUR-WS-SERVER/cable`);

function subscribeToChannel(id) { // конектимся к чат руму
  subscription = cable.subscriptions.create({
    channel: `channel`,
    chat_room_id: id
  }, {
    connected: function() {
      console.log('connected to chat room channel')
    },
    received: function(data) {
      console.log('some massage', data)
    },
    sendMessage: function(message, to) { // добавляем метод sendMessage к сабскрайбу
      console.log(message, to)
      this.perform('send_message', {
        body: message,
        to: to
      });
    }
  });
}

function sendMessage(yourMessage, id) {
  subscription.sendMessage(yourMessage, id) // вызываем тот самый метод sendMessage который мы добавили
}
```